# Set background image to div via JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know this is being asked several times but my problem is I want to set an internet path not the local path. When I set the local path, it works. But when I set http://domain.com/folder/image kind of path, it does not take it. Below is the code I am using. Please help me understand why is it happening.

```
var sImage = "http://domain/Images/" + getParameterByName("id");
$(".container").css("background-image", "url(" + sImage + ")");
```

Here getParameterByName function gets the value of id querystring and while debugging I checked that variable sImage is getting correct value.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Your are using "url(" twice...

Comment: What is the output of `sImage`?